# Information about geo-locations via coordinates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Are there any ways to get information about different places (cities, mountains, rivers , etc) via latitude/longtitude?

I'm planning to use it in my rails project.
Of course, it will be perfect to use information from wiki. Any example of searching over wiki via lat/lon?

May be any other technology/website/api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also check the [Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) gem to find address by latitude and longtitude. Then you can use wiki api to find articles, like this:

en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="place_name"&prop=info&format=xml

Or, maybe  [wikilocation](http://wikilocation.org/documentation/) will help you

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Open Street Map API  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API  They tend to discourage read-only queries, but you can probably find someone else's API for that data.

Also check out http://www.gisgraphy.com/  They have a free webservice here http://www.gisgraphy.com/documentation/user-guide.htm#geolocwebservice that looks like it has what you are looking for.

Comment: I see that OSM has an api here http://www.overpass-api.de/ that they are working on.